# ReactJS checkbox TRUE/FALSE show object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in a form with ReactJS + MUI

I have a checkbox with Boolean TRUE/FALSE

```
<Checkbox
 id="status"
 name="status"
 onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
/>
```

This is the function onInputChange

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
            username: '',
            email: '',
            status: bool,
        });

 const onInputChange = (e) => {
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        console.log(user)
    }
```

On my console.log I'm getting an object rather than the value.

Would you explain me what I'm doing wrong here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checkbox you have to use **checked** property, like this:

You have to send **type** as an extra parameter from onchange function.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        status: bool,
    });

const onInputChange = (e, type) => {
    if (type === 'checkbox') {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked })
    } else {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    console.log(user)
}

<Checkbox
    id="status"
    name="status"
    onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'checkbox')}
/>
```

Comment: Amazing!! This works. The only change I did was to use e.target.type rather than just "type" and works. Thank you!!

Comment: cool, checkbox return boolean value so you have to use e.target.checked @Rolanda, Thanks.